# How to make numpy 2D array back into python list

Tags: python, numpy

```
[array([868., 905.]), array([827., 905.]), array([785., 905.]), array([743., 905.]), array([701., 905.]), array([659., 905.]), array([617., 905.]), array([575., 905.]), array([533., 905.]), array([491., 905.]), array([449., 905.]), array([407., 905.]), array([365., 905.]), array([323., 905.]), array([281., 905.]), array([239., 905.]), array([197., 905.]), array([155., 905.])]
```

I need a way to turn this back into a list. I'm trying to run this code with that information:

```
values= #a is the array in the code above
keys = a
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
#print(dictionary)

a=[]
for i in range(101,173):
    cv=str(i)
    a.append(cv)

print(a)
```

Comment: I suppose you have a list of numpy arrays and you want to convert it to a list of list

Comment: `arrays = [your arrays here]; `   `lists = np.array(arrays).tolist()` or [x.tolist() for x in arrays]

Comment: Hey, you would need to specify exactly how you want your list to be. Like this : `[[868., 905.], [827., 905.], [775., 905.], ...]` ? This : `[868., 905., 827., 905., 775., 905., ...]` ? This : [[869., 827., 775.], [905., 905., 905.]] ? Or any other way? Because numpy arrays already act like a basic python list if that is only what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple list comprehension to do this task.

```
from numpy import array

a = [array([868., 905.]), array([827., 905.]), array([785., 905.]), array([743., 905.]), array([701., 905.]), array([659., 905.]), array([617., 905.]), array([575., 905.]), array([533., 905.]), array([491., 905.]), array([449., 905.]), array([407., 905.]), array([365., 905.]), array([323., 905.]), array([281., 905.]), array([239., 905.]), array([197., 905.]), array([155., 905.])]

l = [list(x) for x in a] # alternaltiely, l = [x.tolist() for x in a]

print(l)

# output
[[868.0, 905.0],
 [827.0, 905.0],
 [785.0, 905.0],
 [743.0, 905.0],
 [701.0, 905.0],
 [659.0, 905.0],
 [617.0, 905.0],
 [575.0, 905.0],
 [533.0, 905.0],
 [491.0, 905.0],
 [449.0, 905.0],
 [407.0, 905.0],
 [365.0, 905.0],
 [323.0, 905.0],
 [281.0, 905.0],
 [239.0, 905.0],
 [197.0, 905.0],
 [155.0, 905.0]]
```

Comment: `x.tolist()` is better than `list(x)`.  The conversion to Python objects is more complete.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I agree with that statement